# pop rows from dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

From the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
print(df1)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
4  2  5
5  2  6
6  2  7
7  2  8
```

I want to pop 2 rows where 'A' == 2, preferably in a single statement like

> df2 = df1.somepopfunction(...)

to generate the following result:

```
print(df1)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
4  2  7
5  2  8
print(df2)
    A  B
0  2  5
1  2  6
```

The [pandas pop function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) sounds promising, but only pops complete colums.

What statement can replace the pseudocode

> df2 = df1.somepopfunction(...)

to generate the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pop` function for remove rows does not exist in pandas, need filter first and then remove filtred rows from `df1`:

```
df2 = df1[df1.A.eq(2)].head(2)
print (df2)
   A  B
4  2  5
5  2  6

df1 = df1.drop(df2.index)
print (df1)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
6  2  7
7  2  8
```

Comment: That would be the workaround. But why doesn't pandas provide a more complex pop function that accepts axis, filter and other parameters, similar to the drop function?

Comment: @Oblomov - Unfortuantely not, `pop` only use basic functionality - pop one column.

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround, but you can pre-filter on conditions and transpose the dataframe, then build a new dataframe out of your results in a single line. This will not actually 'pop' the columns out of the old dataframe, but you can generate a new one from it.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['A'] == 2].T.pop(col) for col in df1[df1['A'] == 2].T.columns)
print(df2)
```

To break it down:

```
pd.DataFrame( # create new data frame
df1[df1['A'] == 2] # condition
.T # transpose so rows are now columns
.pop(col) # pop out columns 
for col in df1[df1['A'] == 2].T.columns) #for all 'rows' (cols) that meet the condition
```